# Plotting line on a clock

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm currently plotting a historgram on a clock in the following way:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
sns.set_context('poster')
sns.set_style('white')
arr = np.random.randint(0, 24, size = 5000)
N = 23
bottom = 2

# create theta for 24 hours
theta = np.linspace(0.0, 2 * np.pi, N, endpoint=False)

# make the histogram that bined on 24 hour
radii, tick = np.histogram(arr, bins = 23)

# width of each bin on the plot
width = (2*np.pi) / N

# make a polar plot
plt.figure(figsize = (12, 8))
ax = plt.subplot(111, polar=True)
bars = ax.bar(theta, radii, width=width, bottom=bottom)

# set the lable go clockwise and start from the top
ax.set_theta_zero_location("N")
# clockwise
ax.set_theta_direction(-1)

# set the label
ticks = ['0:00', '3:00', '6:00', '9:00', '12:00', '15:00', '18:00', '21:00']
ax.set_xticklabels(ticks)

plt.show()
```

This results in the following figure.

[image]

Now I would like to change this so that it is no more a histogram but a line plot showing the mean per bin and a band for the 25 and 75 quantiles. Can this be done in such a clock plot?

Comment: Yes it can, as it's a polar plot. As to how, I look forward to answers

Comment: Do you have any example (maybe for other data) of how your desired result should look like, at least approximately?

Comment: Do you want to have a line that looks similar [to this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HlnI7.png), approximately? Also [this one](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c5/Courbe_polaire_rayon_aleatoire_python_matplotlib.svg).

Comment: @Arty Yes, exactly a line like in your plot (but going all around). Below and above the line there should be a shaded area for displaying the quantiles.

Comment: Note that your last bar is double in height because it lumps together hour 23 and 22.  For discrete data you need bin edges inbetween the values. For example `bins=np.arange(-0.5, 24)`, supposing the hours are integers from 0 till 23.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**PART 1** (of two).

Here I did minimal amount of changes to your code to solve (hopefully correctly) your task.

Gray band on picture is area between 0.25 and 0.75 quantiles.

[Try it online!](https://repl.it/@moytrage/StackOverflow65938587#main.py)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
sns.set_context('poster')
sns.set_style('white')
arr = np.random.randint(0, 24, size = 5000)
N = 23
bottom = 2

# create theta for 24 hours
theta = np.linspace(0.0, 2 * np.pi, N, endpoint=False)

# make the histogram that bined on 24 hour
radii, tick = np.histogram(arr, bins = 23)

# width of each bin on the plot
width = (2*np.pi) / N

# make a polar plot
plt.figure(figsize = (12, 8))
ax = plt.subplot(111, polar=True)
ax.plot(np.append(theta, theta[0]), np.append(radii, radii[0]), linewidth = 4)
ax.fill_between(
    np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 200), np.quantile(radii, 0.25),
    np.quantile(radii, 0.75), color = 'gray',
)

# set the lable go clockwise and start from the top
ax.set_theta_zero_location("N")
# clockwise
ax.set_theta_direction(-1)

# set the label
ticks = ['0:00', '3:00', '6:00', '9:00', '12:00', '15:00', '18:00', '21:00']
ax.set_xticklabels(ticks)

plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

---

Also as @JohanC noted your last bin contains 22 and 23 value, that is why it has a jump. If you change 23->24 in your code (for number of bins, because you actually have 24 distinct values hence should have 24 bins) then you'll get a nice uniform picture (without jumps) like below:

[image]

---

Also I decided to do some experiments, use more bins (48) and draw more quantile bands, this is picture that I got with smooth quantile bands gradient:

[image]

The code used to draw picture above is here:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
np.random.seed(0)
sns.set_context('poster')
sns.set_style('white')
N = 24 * 2
arr = np.random.randint(0, N, size = 5000 * N // 24)
bottom = 2

# create theta for 24 hours
theta = np.linspace(0.0, 2 * np.pi, N, endpoint=False)

# make the histogram that bined on 24 hour
radii, tick = np.histogram(arr, bins = N)

# width of each bin on the plot
width = (2*np.pi) / N

# make a polar plot
plt.figure(figsize = (12, 8))
ax = plt.subplot(111, polar=True)
ax.plot(np.append(theta, theta[0]), np.append(radii, radii[0]), linewidth = 4, color = 'blue')
for q in np.linspace(0.0, 0.5, 50):
    ax.fill_between(
        np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 200), np.quantile(radii, q),
        np.quantile(radii, 1.0 - q), color = (0.1 + (1.0 - 2 * q) * 0.8,) * 3, #plt.cm.jet(2 * q),
    )

# set the lable go clockwise and start from the top
ax.set_theta_zero_location("N")
# clockwise
ax.set_theta_direction(-1)

# set the label
ticks = ['0:00', '3:00', '6:00', '9:00', '12:00', '15:00', '18:00', '21:00']
ax.set_xticklabels(ticks)

plt.show()
```

---

**PART 2**. Got updates on task specifics from question's author.

Apparently it was needed to put numbers 1 to 5 inside each bin. And draw quantiles and variance graphs.

Resulting code is below:

[Try it online!](https://repl.it/@moytrage/StackOverflow65938587var2#main.py)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
np.random.seed(0)
sns.set_context('poster')
sns.set_style('white')
size, nbins, vmin, vmax = 30000, 24, 1, 5
arr = np.random.randint(vmin, vmax + 1, size = (size,))
time = np.random.randint(0, nbins, size = (size,))
barr = [arr[time == bin] for bin in range(nbins)]

plt.figure(figsize = (12, 8))

x = list(np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, nbins, endpoint = False))
for is_var in [False, True]:
    plt.cla()
    
    ax = plt.subplot(111, polar = True)

    # Quantiles
    y = [[np.quantile(barr[bin], q) for q in [0.0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1.0]] for bin in range(nbins)]
    if not is_var:
        ax.fill_between(x + x[:1], [e[0] for e in y] + [y[0][0]], [e[4] for e in y] + [y[0][4]], color = 'lightgray', alpha = 0.5)
        ax.fill_between(x + x[:1], [e[1] for e in y] + [y[0][1]], [e[3] for e in y] + [y[0][3]], color = 'gray', alpha = 0.5)
    ax.plot(x + x[:1], [e[2] for e in y] + [y[0][2]], linewidth = 3, color = 'blue')
    # Variance
    if is_var:
        y2 = [np.var(barr[bin]) for bin in range(nbins)]
        ax.fill_between(x + x[:1], [e1[2] - e2 for e1, e2 in zip(y, y2)] + [y[0][2] - y2[0]],
            [e1[2] + e2 for e1, e2 in zip(y, y2)] + [y[0][2] + y2[0]], color = 'yellow', alpha = 0.2)
        
    # set the lable go clockwise and start from the top
    ax.set_theta_zero_location("N")
    # clockwise
    ax.set_theta_direction(-1)

    # set the label
    ticks = ['0:00', '3:00', '6:00', '9:00', '12:00', '15:00', '18:00', '21:00']
    ax.set_xticklabels(ticks)

    plt.title(('Quantiles', 'Variance')[is_var])
    
    plt.show()
```

Quantiles output:

[image]

Variance output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. Is it also possible to plot the quantiles around the line? For example as here: https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/1217238/6197735/be036856-b39f-11e4-840b-0278b934bd71.png

Comment: @machinery You know why it is not around line on my picture? Because blue line on my picture is not quantile, it is value of data itself. What you have on your link is different. In the middle is the line of 0.5 quantile, it is not data itself. And around it are bands of 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8 quantiles. So you picture has only quantiles. Also picture like yours is only possible to draw if you have a cloud of points, you have just 24 points. You have to have thousands of points to draw such nice picture like you have on link.

Comment: @machinery Look what do I mean about cloud of points, here [I drawn a picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I8Las.png), this is `sin(x) + random` i.e. it is sinusoidal plus some random gaussian noise. It has 5000 points, it is a huge cloud. Only such huge cloud of thousands of points can have nice quantile bands. But in your case you have just a total of 24 different numbers, because you have 24 bins. With 24 numbers you can't have a nicer quantile band than that drawn by me in my answer. Only if you generate more of random points, thousands, then I can draw nicer quantile bands for you.

Comment: I think there is a misunderstanding. What I thought was to calculate the mean value of each bin and visualize this as the line which you have drawn. For each bin I would then calculate either the 25 and 75 quantiles or the variance and then draw the band based on these values. Is that possible? You can assume that we have 30'000 random points.

Comment: @machinery I just drawn at the end of my answer another picture, it has smooth bands gradient for quantiles. Now also I'll try to draw something closer to what you want with your 30000 random points.

Comment: Thanks a lot. To clarify: Each bin has three values (average, 25 quantiles and 75 quantile). The solid line is going through the average values. The lower edge of the band is going through the 25 quantiles of each bin and the upper edge of the band is going through the 75 quantiles of each bin. The area between the lower and upper edge is shaded.

Comment: Similarly for variance: There we have two values per bin (average and variance) and the lower edge of the band is mean - variance and the upper edge mean + variance for each bin.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227971/discussion-between-arty-and-machinery).

Comment: @machinery Updated my answer with **PART 2** with new changes on task specifics, regarding collecting 1 to 5 numbers.

Comment: By the way, Quartile 50 is not the mean but the median

Comment: @machinery Yes, thanks. But for our case of uniformly distributed numbers 1 to 5 median is almost identically equal to mean. That's why I didn't fix my code, because on current plot image you will not notice any difference between median and mean.